# How to Fix Sequelize TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am starting my node development server after migrating my models. How ever I get two Errors:

> a TypeError and And Error in declaring more than one ENUM DataTypes in my Models.

I have tried changing the type of the other `ENUM` fields, and it worked if its only one ENUM field, bu wont work if more than one. I don't know how to deal with the Type Error from `Sequelize camelize()` utility function in the `sequelize` library.

```
A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:94
  return str.trim().replace(/[-_\s]+(.)?/g, (match, c) => c.toUpperCase());
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
>       at str.trim.replace (A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:94:61)
>       at String.replace ()
>       at Object.camelize (A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:94:21)
>       at new HasOne (A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\has-one.js:43:31)
>       at Function. (A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:105:25)
>       at Function.Employee.associate (A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\db\models\employee.js:58:14)
>       at Object.keys.forEach.modelName (A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\db\models\index.js:30:19)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object. (A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\db\models\index.js:28:17)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (A:\Portal_project\customer-portal\Server\api\controllers\customerController.js:1:78)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)

I expect all the `sequelize` migrations to work, and my development server to start. but I kept getting this Type Error.

here is my Employee models

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Employee = sequelize.define('Employee', {
    employee_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    employee_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['employee','super employee','admin', 'super admin']
    },
    email_address: DataTypes.STRING,
    id_type: DataTypes.STRING,
    id_number: DataTypes.STRING,
    id_expiry_date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    date_of_birth: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    nationality: DataTypes.STRING,
    state_of_origin: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone_number: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    marital_status: DataTypes.STRING,
    home_address: DataTypes.STRING,
    local_government_of_origin: DataTypes.STRING,
    religion: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: DataTypes.STRING,
    blood_group: DataTypes.STRING,
    disabilty: DataTypes.STRING,
    department: DataTypes.STRING,
    clearance_level: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['employee', 'supervisor', 'admin', 'super admin']
    },
    date_of_employment: DataTypes.DATE,
    employment_type: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['full tme', 'contract']
    },
    date_of_contract_termination: DataTypes.DATE,
    form_of_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    bank_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    account_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    account_number: DataTypes.STRING,
    bvn: DataTypes.STRING,
    payment_type: DataTypes.STRING,
    salary_amount: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
    spouse_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    spouse_phone_number: DataTypes.STRING,
    spouse_address: DataTypes.STRING,
    next_of_kin_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    next_of_kin_phone_number: DataTypes.STRING,
    next_of_kin_address: DataTypes.STRING

  }, {
    underscored: true,
  });

  Employee.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Employee.hasOne(models.IDCardRequest, {
      as: 'employee_id_request'
    })
  };

  Employee.removeAttribute('id');

  return Employee;
};
```

and the migration file

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Employees', {
      employee_name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      employee_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      role: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.ENUM,
        values: ['employee','super employee','admin', 'super admin']
      },
      email: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      date_of_birth: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
      },
      nationality: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      state_of_origin: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      phone_number: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      marital_status: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      home_address: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      id_type: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      id_number: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      id_expiry_date: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
      },
      bank_name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      account_name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      account_number: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      bvn: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true
      },
      local_government_of_origin: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      religion: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      gender: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      blood_group: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      disability: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      department: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      clearance_level: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.ENUM,
        values: ['employee', 'supervisor', 'admin', 'super admin']
      },
      date_of_employment: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      employment_type: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.ENUM,
        values: ['full time', 'contract']
      },
      date_of_contract_termination: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      form_of_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      payment_type: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      salary_amount: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
      },
       spouse_name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      spouse_number: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      spouse_address: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      next_of_kin_name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      next_of_kin_number: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      next_of_kin_address: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      created_at: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE, 
      },
      updated_at: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Employees');
  }
};
```

See also, the CardRequest Model that belongs to Employee

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const IDCardRequest = sequelize.define('IDCardRequest', {
    card_request_status: DataTypes.ENUM('pending', 'processed'),
    card_renewal_status: DataTypes.ENUM('pending', 'processed')
  }, {
    underscored: true
  });

  IDCardRequest.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    IDCardRequest.BelongsTo(models.Employee,{
      foreignKey: 'employee_id',
      targetKey: 'employee_id',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
  };
  IDCardRequest.removeAttribute('id');
  return IDCardRequest;
};
```

Comment: Can you show the full function code?

Comment: Okay, I will edit as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Try to update ENUM declaration to this one:

```
role: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('employee','super employee','admin', 'super admin'),
      }
```

Comment: I did that already. If I use that syntax, it wont allow more than one enum type definition. At the moment the error is from the index.js file of my models folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by specifying the primary key on my model

```
employee_id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
}
```

looks like it happens when you define associations but did not specify the primary key on your model.

Might be too late for the OP but hope this helps someone else.